# React re-renders unnecessary components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React, so please explain **why** this is happens(I guess because I'm re-creating the array of objects, but I'm not sure and don't know how to fix this) and **how** to fix this this.

I think it's better to show the code, rather than talk about it, so:

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Input from "./Input";

let lastId = 2;

function App() {
  const [inputsValues, setInputsValues] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: "" },
    { id: 2, value: "" },
  ]);

  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    setInputsValues((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      const index = newState.findIndex((input) => input.id === id);
      newState[index].value = e.target.value;
      return newState;
    });
  };

  const addNewInput = () => {
    setInputsValues((prevState) => {
      const newState = [...prevState];
      newState.push({ id: ++lastId, value: "" });
      return newState;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={addNewInput}>Add new input...</button>
      </div>

      {inputsValues.map((input) => (
        <div className="input-wrap">
          <Input
            key={input.id}
            id={input.id}
            value={input.value}
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Input.js

```
import { useRef } from "react";

const Input = ({ id, value, handleChange }) => {
  const renderAmount = useRef(0);

  return (
    <>
      <div> Rendered: {renderAmount.current++}</div>
      <input
        id={id}
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, id)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Thanks

Comment: How to fix what? What is the problem? Why is it causing you issues that components are re-rendered? Is something breaking in your program?

Comment: @AnthonyGarcia-Labiad How to fix re-rendering of other `Input` components when there's a change in `value` of another `Input` component. Why? Because I want to know how to handle this kind of scenarios

Comment: `App` rerenders because it's state is changed. `Input` rerenders because it's properties change (at least `handleChange` is *new* on every App rerender). That being said, `key={input.id}` is on the wrong element. It should be `<div className="input-wrap" key={input.id}>`.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks, I've changed the `key` from `Input` to `div`'s property. As for the `handleChange` being changed... what makes it to change exactly? Doesn't it the same function? How do I fix this then?

Comment: It changes because it *exists* in `App` which rerenders on it's state change. As such on every render its a new function. You could use `useCallback` in combination with Ulrichs answers. Something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-shadow-b1t6y?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @Yoshi So if I want to limit my re-renders only for the component where the change is happened, I need to use `useCallback` for every prop I pass? Is that really the only way?

Comment: Yes and no. You could use refs, contexts or you own solutions. Ultimately it's quite simple. A re-render occurs on state or prop change. If you use `memo` "prop change re-renders" can be minimized as long as you pass in properties that can be compared using `===`. To have a non scalar (callbacks) value work here, you need some way to *memonize* them. That's why `useCallback` works.

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks a lot, buddy! Thanks to you, it's way more clear now. So the non-scalar props are memoized with `useCallback` on the parent component and entire `Input` function memoized with `memo`? So on each key of the input, I will produce new `Input`s `props` inside memoized `Input`. So... I will end up with all of the history of my props, right?

Comment: @Yoshi, let me rephrase the prev. comment of mine, as I was editing it a lot: So the non-scalar props are memoized with `useCallback` on the parent component and the rest of the props are memoized within the `Input` function with `memo`? So on each key of the input, I will produce new `Input`s `props` inside memoized `Input`. So... I will end up with all of the history of my props, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230256/discussion-between-yoshi-and-galaxyriot).

Comment: @Yoshi, you're awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you just have to wrap your Input component in `memo` so that it only rerenders if its props change. So i imported the memo function in the top and called it on the right side of the assignment, so that it 'wraps' your component and makes it memoized.

```js
import { useRef, memo } from "react";

const Input = memo(({ id, value, handleChange }) => {
  const renderAmount = useRef(0);

  return (
    <>
      <div> Rendered: {renderAmount.current++}</div>
      <input
        id={id}
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, id)}
      />
    </>
  );
});

export default Input;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I actually tried that before and yet, tried this again, and this still rerender other `Inputs` when some of them is changed

Comment: ah okay. and you need to wrap your `handleChange` with `useCallback` so that it is also memoized between render calls and doesnt change: `const handleChange = useCallback((e, id) => {...}, [])`

Comment: Great! Could mark the question as accepted answer?